# How can i disable a scrollview?

Tags: android

I am using relativelayout and inside it a scrollview and inside it a linear layout and a textview which is ensuring scrolling of textview, but I do not want to scroll the text after the particular condition. So, what can I do for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make the scrollbars invisible use this attribute.

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

Edit:

if there is need of runtime changes on visibility or state of enabling, for that we can use the `scrolview.setEnabled(false)` or `android:enabled=false`.

Comment: I am asking to scrolling to get disable when particular condition gets false.So, changes must be done in source code

Comment: then use `android:enabled=false` or `scrolview.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: Kindly update this comment to your answer,such that viewer can see it first time

Answer (score 9):

There is no direct way to stop scrollview to scroll but u can do it in other way Like:

```
//global boolean variable
boolean enable = true;    

scrollview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
   {

      return !enable;
   }
});
```

when you set **enable** variable to **true** it will start scrolling and when you set it to false it stop scrolling.

Comment: this is the best answer. I don't know why is the other answer accepted. This one should be accepted as real answer. I've tried previous, and it's not working. setEnabled on a ScrollView is not applicable. This listener works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a better code for the answer in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5090420/887894

Answer (score 1):

If I interpreted your question correctly, you probably want to extend ScrollView and write your own implementation of onInterceptTouchEvent. You could then make your ScrollView conditionally ignore touch events, thus disabling the scrolling behavior. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229178/disable-scroll-view-action) for more details.