# Edit text inside scroll view is not scrollable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext, scrollview

I have searched for the solution but it seems those are not working. Is it my case not applicable for changing the xml? How to fix the problem ? The scroll view work but the edittext not working. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/share_bg" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photo_area"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/share_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/photo_area"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/share_title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/share_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/share_title"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_textarea"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:lines="5"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="@string/default_msg" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/share_submit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/share_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/photo_taken_btn_submit" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The id: share_content is the editText, Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, how exactly is it not working? What about it isn't working?

Comment: scroll view work but the edittext not working. When I scroll on edittext, it move the scroll view Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812892/enable-scrollable-edittext-within-a-scrollview-and-viewflipper?rq=1)?

Comment: Thanks using programmitically way works

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605486/edit-text-not-scrollable-inside-scroll-view) link. You will get the answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can perform this to make an edittext scrollable:

```
 EditText EtOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment1);
EtOne.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.comment1) {
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

See "[Scrolling editbox inside scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9770252/1430996)"

Comment: Could you clarify the purpose of MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I was able to shorten the entire if block to just `v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(! ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP));` though, it looks cleaner to me.