# EditText not scrollable inside NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-nestedscrollview

**Layout:** I have an EditText and 2 RecyclerViews inside a NestedScrollView, which are not visible (visibility=gone)

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    //... toolbar

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin"
                    android:singleLine="false" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_items"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
   
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_Labels"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
        
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?actionBarSize" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            //...
    />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The problem:** When I enter more text than the height of the screen, the EditText is scrolled down to where the cursor is. But when I try to scroll up, nothing happens. [Here's a screen recording I made.](https://youtu.be/aGcg7GZeO2M)

Can't scroll:

- after entering/pasting long text for the 1st time.

Can scroll:

- after reopening the activity with text already entered
- after closing the keyboard
- after closing the keyboard and opening it again

**Searching for similar problems yielded:**

- [EditText not scrollable inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605486/edittext-not-scrollable-inside-scrollview)
- [Enable Scrollable EditText within a ScrollView and ViewFlipper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812892/enable-scrollable-edittext-within-a-scrollview-and-viewflipper/13815747#13815747)
- ... and other results with the same answer:

...

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.editText) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

That solution doesn't work:

1. The questions are about ScrollViews, not NestedScrollViews. And NestedScrollView is one of the proposed solutions (which I already use)
2. When I add the above code, the EditText is sort of scrollable, but only when the keyboard is shown. If it is not, then it's impossible to scroll - trying to scroll causes text to be selected.
3. Scrolling (with the keyboard open) moves the cursor.

Please let me know if you need any more info or if I've missed anything. Thank you!

Comment: @HenriqueMS I removed the LinearLayout that wrapped NestedScrollView, same behavior

Comment: @HenriqueMS That would mean the edittext would be in a LinearLayout in a NestedScrollView nested in a NestedScrollView... Didn't work.

Comment: @HenriqueMS Perhaps you could post your code? I might have misunderstood your prior directions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is actually simpler than I thought.
After pasting your xml (and making the necessary changes for it to build - missing dimens. etc...) I just changed the height of your `EditText` to `wrap_content` and the bug was gone.

The answer lies here:
Comparing the measurements of the `EditText` at different points in time, on the left with `height=match_parent` and on the right with `height=wrap_content`

On the left:
The `EditText` is drawn on screen empty with a certain size, you paste the text and it's size doesn't change. **Showing/Hiding the keyboard** is one important event in the life of a screen, it's called a **configuration change** this causes elements to be measured again and re-drawn.

On the right:
If you change the height of the `EditText` to `wrap_content` it will force a measure and re-draw immediately after insertion.

[image: Measurement of EditText at different times]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I thought setting wrap_content to the EditText would make the clickable area very small, but it doesn't. And this solution works, thank you! :)

Comment: Follow-up question: What tool did you use to get the measurements?

Comment: No problem ;) you can do it in several ways the easiest is to use layout inspector while running the app with the debugger (tools menu I think) https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Answer (score -1):

set activity as,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```