# ScrollView: Pass touch events to children

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I made a "joystick" out of an `ImageView`. It is inside a `ScrollView`.

It works without the `ScrollView` but inside the `ScrollView` it does not receive `TouchEvents` for vertical movement.

How can I stop the `ScrollView` from blocking the touch event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling).

I created a custom ScrollView class that has a boolean indicating whether it is locked.
The onInterceptTouchEvent method is overridden:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (!mScrollable) return false;
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

When the joystick is touched (ACTION_DOWN), the custom ScrollView is locked. At the ATCTION_UP event it is unlocked.

Answer (score 6):

You're going to want to toggle this on and off as needed..

getParent().[requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29)(true).

I'm not exactly sure why you have the joystick in a scroll view, is the joystick also supposed to be scrolling with the view?  If this is what is intended, the route above would be the best solution.  If it's not supposed to be scrolling with the view, I'll help you work out a better method of including the joystick in your view.

Comment: This has no effect, regardless of whether I call it for the ScrollView or its parent, with true or false. I need a ScrollView because the user could add as many joysticks as he wants. It would be ok to disable scrolling for the ImageView but I want the ScrollView to be scrollable touching other views.

Comment: No effect?  You should be calling it joystickView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)... Is this how you're calling it?  Take a look at [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229178/disable-scrollview-action) post.  I disagree with the elegance of the top rated answer, but that should also do the job.

Comment: Okay I implemented it like in the link. Now it does not scroll anymore. But vertical movements are still not detected by the ImageView (while horizontal movements are detected).

Answer (score -1):

simple answer is here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34436589/3818437

Declare your ScrollView not clickable / focusable by using

```
android:clickable="false" and android:focusable="false"
```

or

`v.setClickable(false) and v.setFocusable(false)`.

The click events should be dispatched to the ScrollView's parent now.