# Android : detect click event at empty space of gridview inside linearlayout

Tags: android

I have a following problem. I have a `GridView` inside `LinearLayout` as image below. I want to detect click event when user click at empty space of `GridView`, in the image, the location that I want is the red area and also inside the green area.

But I have following problems.

1. If I add `onClickListener` for `GridView`: error because Adapter cannot add click event.
2. If I add `onItemClickListener` for `GridView`: I just can detect where exist items (in the image is the white box)
3. If I add `onClickListener` for `LinearLayout` I just can detect click event on green area, not red area.

So how can I fix above problem.

@Edit: my layout looks like:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <GridView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-the-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the parent LinearLayout can be assigned its own `OnClickListener`, the issue is only how to detect a click within the GridView that occurs outside of its child Views. You can subclass GridView and override the `dispatchTouchEvent()` method to accomplish this. Using the `pointToPosition()` method, we can determine if a touch event occurs outside of the child Views, and use an interface to notify a listener if it is. In the following example, the `OnNoItemClickListener` interface provides that functionality.

```
public class TouchyGridView extends GridView
{
    // Depending on how you're creating this View,
    // you might need to specify additional constructors.
    public TouchyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private OnNoItemClickListener listener;
    public interface OnNoItemClickListener
    {
        public void onNoItemClick();
    }

    public void setOnNoItemClickListener(OnNoItemClickListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        // The pointToPosition() method returns -1 if the touch event
        // occurs outside of a child View.
        // Change the MotionEvent action as needed. Here we use ACTION_DOWN
        // as a simple, naive indication of a click.
        if (pointToPosition((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()) == -1
            && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            if (listener != null)
            {
                listener.onNoItemClick();
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyother way to implement this without creating separate class ?

Answer (score 3):

Declare your GridView not clickable / focusable by using

> android:clickable="false" and android:focusable="false"

or

```
v.setClickable(false) and v.setFocusable(false)
```

The click events should be dispatched to the GridView's parent now.

> **Note:** In order to achieve this, you have to add click to its direct parent. or set android:clickable="false" and
>   android:focusable="false" to its direct parent to pass listener to
>   further parent.

thnx to SIYB's answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959830/3818437

Comment: this is a good way for a solution so please don't spam downvotes unless this answer is NOT USEFUL.

Answer (score 1):

U can just set both OnItemClickListener and OnTouchListener and 
Handle Grid View empty area clicks inside OnTouchListener.

```
    gridViewVar.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View VyuIdxPsgVar,
                int IdxPsgVal, long id)
        {
            // Code Something todo on item clicked
        }
    });
    gridViewVar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            if (gridViewVar.pointToPosition((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()) == -1
                    && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                // Code Something todo on empty space
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: this works for me. and more simple than using a custom GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you put **onClickListener** on wrong layout (you put it only on inner/green area layout and not on global RelativeLayout wich can catch clicks from grid and linear layouts both).

Comment: in fact. linear layout is a container of gridview. but maybe because grid view is above, so at red area, clicking event cannot come into linear layout. :(

Comment: I do not think that this is a reason. But you can create one single onClickListener and add it to Linear and Grid layouts both.

Comment: as three tests above, no test cases can detect red area section. So, I think add click listener for both layout will not work

Comment: Just set to Grid setOnTouchListener, do not forget to return true/false according to app logic. OnTouchListener will handle every touch events on this layout.