# RecyclerView not clickable

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have a `LinearLayout` with a nested `RecyclerView` showing a list of items. I'd like to open a popup when `RecyclerView` is clicked (either one of the items or the background white area), but the usual `setOnClickListener` is not working.

Of course I can put a click listener on each of the items, but the white area between them remains unclickable.

Is there a way to make the entire `RecyclerView` area clickable?

---

**EDIT:** I've added some sample code. I'd like to have the entire layout clickable to open a popup, but while the first three views behave properly, the `RecyclerView` does not.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_half"
        android:background="@color/color_item_margin_divider"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fragment_tags_title"
        style="@style/ItemFragmentHeader"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_line"
        android:background="@color/color_line_divider"/>
    <RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_half"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should post your code. Also, check your parent views as they may capture click events. You can disable it by adding `android:clickable="true"` to parent's XML- that may help.

Comment: Please post some code and we help you

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703779/detect-click-on-recyclerview-outside-of-items

Comment: So it seems I have to check separately for items and whitespace, there's no way to track the entire area....

Answer (score 0):

Add `onClickListener` in the `viewHolder` . Below is a snippet of my project where I had implemented `Listener`

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       public ImageView shotThumbnail;
       public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                    super(view);
                    shotThumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.shotThumbnail);
                    shotThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            //Put here stuff that you want the onclickListener should do 

                        }
                    });
```

Check if this link helps: 
[Detect click on RecyclerView outside of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703779/detect-click-on-recyclerview-outside-of-items)

Comment: As I said in the question, the entire RecyclerView area must be clickable, not only the single items but even their margins...

Comment: Share an image of the it and probable mark the area you want to make clickable?

Comment: Have you kept some padding explicitly ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use padding instead of margin.

```xml
    <RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_padding="@dimen/spacing_half"/>
```

Cause whenever you use padding it will crop your RecyclerView. But whenever you use padding it will just shorten your inside functions. hence you need padding. Then you should use an onClickListener in MainActivity.

```java
recyclerView.setOnClickListener(v->{
  //Do whatever you want
});
```